# How to safely edit commits on a github repository?

Tags: git, github

I have been working on a complicated github project which involved making many changes to the repository over and over again. Sometimes I ended up making many nasty and some times unnecessary commit messages that are making it it very difficult for new developers to understand how the project works.

What would be the safest way for me to edit the commits and commit messages ?
Currently I have 78 commits and I would like to make changes to previous commits (for example squash commit 34-38 or maybe edit to message of commit 51 and so on).

Comment: Have you done any research? For example: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I think you are misreading my question. I am fully aware of how to amend (The latest) commit message or maybe rebase(Last x ) Commits. I have asked a different question.

Comment: I would like to know a way to amend commit messages (even other than the last one). And I would also like to squash commits the same way.

Comment: Yep, it also tells you how to squash multiple commits and edit multiple commit messages. It's also not the only guidance available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the **safe** part: Always keep a backup of your repository around and make sure you create a backup (by copying the directory to some other location) before you do anything that messes with git history.

As long as it is only the order of the commits and the messages you want to change, I find git's interactive rebase (`git rebase -i <sha-of-the-first-commit-you-want-tochange>`) the most intuitive solution. It will open the commit history in an editor and you can change the order of commits by moving around lines and squash commits by prepending lines with `squash`. The most important options and usage is documented when you open it.

Note that this will change all the commit IDs, so you will need to force-push it to remotes that have the **old** history. If your repo has any forks or is developed by others, make sure you inform them and consider whether a cleaner history is worth the trouble for everyone.